# How to align non-numbered and numbered chapters in memoir with non-standard spacing?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have a memoir document with custom TOC spacing:

```latex
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum} {\quad}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}    {\cftsectiondotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}      {\cftsectionfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}    {\cftsectionleader}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}  {\cftsectionpagefont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}   {\hfill}
\setlength   {\cftbeforechapterskip}{0.5em}
\setlength   {\cftchapternumwidth}  {10em}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{Alpha}
\chapter{Beta}
\end{document}
```

This generates a TOC like this:

[image]

I cannot find any memoir options to give non-numbered entries a space at the beginning so that I can line up the Preface entry with the numbered chapter names (i.e. Preface left-aligned with Alpha). Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines after loading the `memoir` class.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@chapter
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\f@rtoc}}%
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline{}\f@rtoc}}%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother
```

This will handle only the preface. `\chapter*` headings in the main part are handled differently. For these, it is sufficient to add the line

```
\renewcommand\memchapstarinfo[2]{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline{}#1}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@chapter
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\f@rtoc}}%
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline{}\f@rtoc}}%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\memchapstarinfo[2]{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline{}#1}}  
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum} {\quad}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}    {\cftsectiondotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}      {\cftsectionfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}    {\cftsectionleader}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}  {\cftsectionpagefont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}   {\hfill}
\setlength   {\cftbeforechapterskip}{0.5em}
\setlength   {\cftchapternumwidth}  {10em}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{Alpha}
\section{Alpha 1}
\section{Alpha 2}
\chapter*{Beta}
\section{Beta 1}
\section{Beta 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess memoir doesn't deal with this case specifically.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that this does not work for more than one entry. In my actual document, I have multiple non-numbered entries before and after the numbered entries. Could this solution be adapted for this more general situation?

Comment: @Roxy This is a different, easier story, see the extended answer.